# How to pass an instance variable to a erb template in a Sinatra route?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

How do I pass an instance variable to an erb template in a Sinatra route. The below doesn't work.

```
   get '/' do
    
       @beercompany = "Coors"
       erb :mytemplate
    end
```

mytemplate.erb

```
<h1> Hello from <% @beercompany %></h1>
```

output doesn't show beercompany's name

```
Hello from
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put = to display the variable:

```
<h1> Hello from <%= @beercompany %></h1>
```